# mysql_fetch_assoc equivalent for informix

Tags: php, mysql, informix

I just started to work on informix.( I have been using mysql all my life)
how i substitute mysql_fetch_assoc for informix.
Lets say I want to display one item at a time.normally in mysql i would run a while loop like this:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    echo $row['name'];
    echo $row['number'];
}
```

How do i do that for informix?

```
$sql="select * employee";
 $result=$dbh->dbRequest("$sql")
```

Comment: what does `$result` contain? Have you done a `var_dump()`? I would say it contains an array

Comment: What library are you using? I don't see a dbRequest here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.ifx.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using PDO with the informix driver. The manual has plenty of examples of executing and returning data from queries using PDO.

PDO Informix driver - http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-informix.php
PDO prepare - http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

```
$db = new PDO('informix:DSN=db', '', '');
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM employee');
$query->execute();

while ($employee = $query->fetchObject()) {
    echo $employee->name;
    echo $employee->number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic Perl DBI question, though there isn't a `dbRequest` method in the DBI, at least not AFAIK.

You should be using something like this, though I'm assuming you have `$dbh->{RaiseError} = 1` or are otherwise going to add error checking to the code:

```
my $sql = "select * from employee";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute;
my $hashref;

while ($hash_ref = $sth->fetchrow_hashref())
{
    print "$hash_ref->{name}\n";
    print "$hash_ref->{number}\n";
}
```

This is DBMS-neutral; if you're using Perl DBI with MySQL, Informix, Oracle, DB2, ... this is the way you'd write the code.

NB: I edited the tags to add Perl and DBI and MySQL (and dropped the SQL and syntax tags).  If I've misinterpreted your question and you're using PHP instead of Perl, then you should have tagged the code with PHP in the first place (and should now retag it).  There is no SQL issue worth mentioning here; it is all about how to use SQL in the (formally unidentified) host language.

There's a different answer if the question is PHP, using the PDO system.